# How do I get multiple conditions to be met?

Tags: excel, vba

```
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value = "ER" Or "ER BACK" Then
     
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Cut
     Worksheets("ER").Activate
     b = Worksheets("ER").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Worksheets("ER").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
     End If
Next
```

Would like to seek your expertise in this matter.

I wish to add an additional condition to my current code that works well with a single condition.

As I googled for ideas on how to improve it. Came across a suggestion that I just have to add in OR (second condition) and code will be good to go. However I faced an error message of Run-time error 13: Type mismatch.

appreciate any feedbacks for this! Thanks in advance!

Code with 1 Condition (ER)

[image]

Outcome of code with 1 Condition (ER)

[image]

Intention to add a SECOND condition

[image]

To add to the list in (Second Image)

[image]

Comment: [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) may be easier to use here. Also, are there any cells with error values in column E?

Comment: thank you so much! it really help with my project! Cheers and appreciate it!